# INSERT INTO SELECT: mix between select column and plain values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

```sql
INSERT INTO "ApiToken" ("ownerId", token, name) 
SELECT u.id, u."apiToken", "Default" 
FROM "User" u
```

Here, I'd like "name" to be set to a plain value "Default", but the query interprets this as "getting the Default column from User":

`column "Default" does not exist`

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Try to give `Default` value in single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Why are you using quotes for column names and table names? Remove them all.

Comment: Of course, I'll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS